# Calculating sum of products using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have list of products for users to select. When user selects a product, the price is displayed and the user enters the quantity to calculate the total price for all selected products.

Now with my code, the total price for the first selected product appears the same for all other products selected afterwards. i.e

If user selects `Fifa and PRO` the total price for FIFA appears for PRO as below

```
Item : Fifa    
Price : 100eu    
Quantity : 4    
Total price : 400eu  

Item : PRO     
Price: 50eu    
Quantity: 1    
Total Price: 400eu
```

But this is what i am looking to have

```
Item : Fifa            
Price : 100eu            
Quantity : 4            
Total price : 400eu          

Item : PRO             
Price: 50eu            
Quantity: 1            
Total Price: 50eu

Total Order Price = 400eu + 50eu = 450eu
```

**JS**

```
public selectGame(game){
     $(".gameshop").append(
            '<p id="name">Item: ' + game.name + '</p>'+
            '<p name="price" id="price" data-price="'+game.price+'"> Price  :  ' + game.price + '</p>'+
            '<input type="text"  onKeyUp="final()" id="quantity"  name="quantity" />' +
            '<p id="final_price">Total Price  $:<span></span></p>').appendTo('form')    
}

function final()
{        
    a = Number($('#quantity').val());
    b = Number($('#price').data("price"));
    c = a * b;

    $("#final_price span").text(c);    
}
```

**HTML**

```
        <form class="form-horizontal" method="post">
    @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
    <p class="alert alert-danger">{{ $error }}</p>
    @endforeach
    @if (session('status'))
    <div class="alert alert-success">
            {{ session('status') }}
        </div>
    @endif
    {!! csrf_field() !!}
    <fieldset>

    <div class="panel label_container">
<input onclick="return selectGame(this)" type="checkbox" id="{!! $game->id !!}" " /> 
   <label class="mylabel" >  </label>

</div>
    <legend>Games</legend> 

    <div class="gameshop" id="gameshop">



    </div>


            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
```

**Update**

```
 function selectGame(game)
{

    $('.gameshop').append(
        '<div class="item">'+
        '<p class="name"> Item: ' + game.name + '</p>'+
        '<p class="price"   data-price="'+game.price+'"> Price  :  ' + game.price + '</p>'+
        '<input type="text"   class="quantity" name="quantity" />'+
        '<p class="total">Total Price  $:<span></span></p>'+
         '</div>'

    )

    $('.gameshop').on('keyup','.quantity',function()

       {

        var a = Number($(this).val());
        var b = Number($(this).closest('div').find('.price').data('price'));

        alert(b);



       });

}
```

Comment: Show use your HTML too

Comment: You're using `id` selectors, which means there should only be one instance of any of those selected elements on your page.

Comment: @SanchitPatiyal HTML added

Comment: @Amateur: That "HTML" looks like it has some potentially server-side templating system being employed.  Is that really the *actual HTML* that's in the browser?  Because one can't help but notice that your `selectGame()` function is never called and the elements being targeted by your jQuery selectors don't exist.

Comment: @David Don't downvote me now, i left out the checkbox.

Comment: @Amateur and I can't see div with class `gameshop` in your html

Comment: @Amateur: So what is the state of the HTML when the JavaScript is executing?  Given what you're showing us, it's *very likely* that you have repeated `id` values in your HTML, which is invalid.  Even if you switch to using a `class` instead, you'd be trying to get/set values of *multiple* elements, which doesn't really make sense.  Your `final()` function seems like it should be (1) attached using `.on()` to a jQuery selection and (2) fetching values relative to its event sender, rather than globally on the page.

Comment: @SanchitPatiyal, it is below the `<legend>Games</legend>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few steps to correct this, since there are a couple of simultaneous problems.  Namely (1) you're re-using `id` values in your HTML and (2) you're trying to get and update values globally on the page when you want to get do so *relatively* to the element invoking the event.

First, replace all of your `id`s in your dynamic HTML string with `class` values instead.  This will prevent the HTML from being invalid by re-using `id` values.  Something like:

```
'<p class="name">Item: ' + game.name + '</p>'+
//... and so on
```

Also, remove your `onKeyUp` inline handler from the `<input>` element:

```
'<input type="text" class="quantity" name="quantity" />'+
```

Next, bind your `keyup` event using jQuery and event delegation.  Have a single declared event handler on a parent element to handle the event:

```
$('.gameshop').on('keyup', '.quantity', function () {
    //...
});
```

This event handler *replaces* your `final()` function.  This should take care of the multiple-`id` problem, but now inside this event handler we need to navigate the DOM to find the elements you're looking for.

First, wrap your dynamic elements in a container of some sort.  Any `<div>` will do.  Something like:

```
'<div class="product">'+    // <--- here
'<p class="name">Item: ' + game.name + '</p>'+
//...
'<p class="final_price">Total Price  $:<span></span></p>'+
'</div>'    // <--- and here
```

Then we can use that container as a stopping point to navigate up and down the DOM to find the target elements.  First, we can find the "quantity" from the event-throwing element itself.  So instead of this:

```
a = Number($('#quantity').val());
```

We can just use the element itself:

```
var a = Number($(this).val());
```

For other values, it's a neighboring element.  This would involve navigating up and down the DOM to find that element.  So instead of this:

```
b = Number($('#price').data("price"));
```

You can do something like this:

```
var b = Number($(this).closest('div').find('.price').data('price'));
```

Notice how it starts from the element throwing the event (`this`), navigates up to the container (`<div>`), then back down to the target element (`.price`).  This should identify the specific element you want to find, relative to the one throwing the event.

**Repeat these same corrections for your other elements, selectors, etc.**

There *could* very well be other issues here, but these appear to be the main structural/logical problems you're encountering.  (Another potential problem could be that strange combined use of `.append()` and `.appendTo()`, I'm not really sure what that's accomplishing.  You should only need one of those.)

Comment: This line `var b = Number($(this).closest('div').find('.price').data('price'));` returns NaN.

Comment: @Amateur: Do some debugging.  Is the `div` found?  Is the `.price` element found?  Does it have a `data-price` attribute?  Does that attribute contain a valid number?

Comment: @Amateur: That code should be producing syntax errors because you have an un-closed single-quote.  The syntax highlighting in the question is showing you where.

Comment: I have corrected the syntax error but then i still get NaN

Comment: @Amateur: Ok, have you debugged at all?  Break apart that line into multiple steps and see which one fails.  Use your browser's debugging tools to examine the current state of the HTML that code is using.

Comment: Well, i am quite sure the line doesn't receive the content

Comment: @Amateur: What do you mean by that?  `data-price` doesn't contain a number?  Well, that would certainly explain why parsing it to a number fails...

Comment: `data-price` contains a number because i am able to display that. But i mean i can't tell why it is failing

Comment: @Amateur: Then this is a good time to do some debugging.  That one line of code does several things.  In your browser's debugging tools, place a breakpoint on that line.  While execution is paused there, use the debugging console to try each operation individually.  What does `$(this).closest('div')` return?  What does `$(this).closest('div').find('.price')` return?  What does `$(this).closest('div').find('.price').data('price')` return?

Answer (score 0):

You are appending dynamically tags with same ids, consider adding something to the id such

```
id="xxx"+"_"+i
```

being i an index